# Rails3: Nested Restful routes with to_param are inversed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

## # Explaining the context

```rb
puts "I am learning Rails, building a simple forum application."
puts "I am pretty satisfied to where I got so far but routes... "
puts "...still figuring them out."
puts "Been 2 days trying all sorts of things."
puts "This is where I am now, and something is not working as expected."
puts "Any help/pointers would be appreciated! :)"
```

## # config/routes.rb

```rb
scope "/helpcenter" do
  resources :cat, :controller => "forums", :as => :forums do
    resources :topics , :controller => "forum_topics", :as => :topics
    resources :posts, :controller => "forum_posts", :as => :posts
  end
end

match "/helpcenter" => "forums#index", :as => :forums
```

## # app/models/forum.rb

```rb
class Forum < ActiveRecord::Base
  def to_param
    "#{id}-#{name.parameterize}"
  end
end
```

## # app/models/forum_topic.rb

```rb
class ForumTopic < ActiveRecord::Base
  def to_param
    "#{id}-#{name.parameterize}"
  end
end
```

## # app/controllers/forums/show.hmtl.erb

```rb
link_to @forum_topic.name, forum_topic_path(@forum_topic)
# OR
link_to @forum_topic.name, @forum_topic
```

## # What is being generated by link_to :

```rb
"/helpcenter/cat/1-first-topic/topics/1-first-forum"
```

## # What I expected to see (because topics should be in forums):

```rb
"/helpcenter/cat/1-first-forum/topics/1-first-topic"
```

## # What am I doing wrong?

```rb
puts "Thanks!"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary paths should be:

```
forum_topic_path(@forum, @topic)  
forum_topics_path(@forum)
```

The param (@forum_topic) you passed in

```
link_to @forum_topic.name, forum_topic_path(@forum_topic)
```

Has one :id associated with it (1), so it will show the forum with id=1. You should also be passing the topic id

```
forum_topic_path(@forum, @topic)
```

Surprised you didn't get an error without the id--I am guessing that it inferred the :id to both resources.

Comment: Indeed, I did not get any errors.  Thank you (and thanks to @Alper too).  For some reasons, non of the online ressources I've read talked about passing two objects to the _path helpers.  Works like a charm now.  thanks for the extra information which gets you the accepted answer!

Answer (score 1):

Hi i think you want to generate a link to a special topic of a special forum.

So you need 2 ids ( - or 2 intances, one for forum, one for topic) when you generate link.

```
link_to @forum_topic.name, forum_topic_path(@forum, @forum_topic)
```